# Modify the SSL certificate for Chef Server

Tags: ssl, chef-infra, knife

I am currently running a Chef Server.

There are 2 ways to access the server :

```
<HOSTNAME_OF_SERVER_OR_FQDN>
OR
<ACTUAL_URL_THAT_SHOULD_BE_OR_CNAME>
```

When I try to run `knife ssl check`, I get:

```
root@host:/opt/chef-server/embedded/jre# knife ssl check
Connecting to host <ACTUAL_URL_THAT_SHOULD_BE_OR_CNAME>:443
ERROR: The SSL certificate of <HOSTNAME_OF_SERVER_OR_FQDN> could not be verified
Certificate issuer data: /C=US/ST=MA/L=Boston/O=YouCorp/OU=Operations/CN=<HOSTNAME_OF_SERVER_OR_FQDN>.com/emailAddress=you@example.com

Configuration Info:

OpenSSL Configuration:
* Version: OpenSSL 1.0.1p 9 Jul 2015
* Certificate file: /opt/chefdk/embedded/ssl/cert.pem
* Certificate directory: /opt/chefdk/embedded/ssl/certs
Chef SSL Configuration:
* ssl_ca_path: nil
* ssl_ca_file: nil
* trusted_certs_dir: "/root/.chef/trusted_certs"
```

I want the `knife ssl check` command to be successful. Basically I want it to be able to successfully connect using `<ACTUAL_URL_THAT_SHOULD_BE_OR_CNAME>`

How can I add the CNAME to the current certificate which I believe is `/opt/chefdk/embedded/ssl/cert.pem` ?

One strange aspect about the certificate file is that when I try to read it and grep for the Hostnames or CNAMES, I do not find any :

```
# /opt/chef-server/embedded/jre/bin/keytool  -printcert -file /opt/chefdk/embedded/ssl/cert.pem | grep <ACTUAL_URL_THAT_SHOULD_BE_OR_CNAME>
No result

# /opt/chef-server/embedded/jre/bin/keytool  -printcert -file /opt/chefdk/embedded/ssl/cert.pem | grep <HOSTNAME_OF_SERVER_OR_FQDN>
No result
```

Answer (score 1):

[this is how i did it in the past](https://docs.chef.io/server_security.html#ssl-certificates)

> The Chef server can be configured to use SSL certificates by adding the following settings to the server configuration file
>
> For example:
>
> `nginx['ssl_certificate']  = "/etc/pki/tls/certs/your-host.crt"`
>   `nginx['ssl_certificate_key']  = "/etc/pki/tls/private/your-host.key"`
>
> Save the file, and then run the following command:
>
> `$ sudo chef-server-ctl reconfigure`